# Laravel 5.1 how to redirect back to the current page after validation fails?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, redirect, routes

I have this path:

```
Route::get('forgotten-password/confirm/{code}'
```

And I want after validation failing to return to this exact path, but it redirects me one step more to

```
Route::get('forgotten-password')
```

I use Request classes, so it automatically makes the validations and returns me back. If it was custom in the controller, I could make:

```
if ($validator->fails())
{
    return redirect('forgotten-password/confirm/{code}');
}
```

Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: If the code isn't correct, Doesn't it fall into `Redirect Loop`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'name' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }


    }
```